# Software for 3D Processing

Tags: open-source, software-development, 3d, microsoft-excel, csv

I have a project for my work which requires me to take XYZ data from a CSV/Excel file using this data I need to generate a 3D line/spline then using this I need to render small segments of a pipe structure with a 3d viewer this can be on a browser or local software running on a laptop or tablet I have searched online and found three.js and babylon.js but I am just wondering if there are any other solutions/software that may facilitate this need or if there are any libraries or ideas that you guys could recommend for me to use I would be very grateful thank you.

Kind Regards,
Fello dude.